# Please Solve this sqlite error

Tags: sql, sqliteopenhelper

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Over_the_horizon.mp3 (code 1): , while compiling: insert into musics(song_name,album_name,artist_name,full_path) values(Over_the_horizon.mp3,Samsung,Samsung,a/storage/emulated/0/Samsung/Music/Over_the_horizon.mp3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String literals in SQL are denoted by single quotes (`'`), which your `values` clause is missing.
Add them and you should be OK:

```
INSERT INTO musics 
(song_name, album_name, artist_name, full_path) 
VALUES ('Over_the_horizon.mp3',
        'Samsung',
        'Samsung',
        'a/storage/emulated/0/Samsung/Music/Over_the_horizon.mp3')
```